# How do I make my document look like this?

Tags: graphics, typography

I want my document to look like this. It is an extract from the Calculus solutions book by James Stewart.

I would like to know something about the following:

- **fonts** (I guess Times New Roman was used.)
- **typesetting** (Was LaTeX or rather MS Word used to typeset?)
- **graphics** (What kind of graphics package was used?)

It would be even better if someone could remake the page in LaTeX or MS Word, whatever was used.

Picture:

[image]

Extract from Calculus, James Stewart.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  See [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919)

Comment: Font is Times (or lookalike), but not in math mode (I don't see a reason for that). LaTeX to typeset, and the figures seem to use times for math, so may be they have been done in another program and just included. However you can also draw them with TikZ for instance.

Comment: What font is used in math mode? In addition, what program except for TikZ could have been used in this particular example?

Comment: The 'y' in inline math is different from the one in that graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must compile with xelatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[9.] $xy=0\Leftrightarrow x=0 \;\text{or}\; y=0.$ the graph consist of the cordinate axes\\

%graph left side==============================================
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
\draw [->] (0,-4) -- (0,4)node[anchor=north east]{$y$};
\draw [->] (-4,0) --(0,0)node[anchor=north east]{$0$}-- (4,0)node[anchor=north east] {$x$};
\draw [<->](0,1.5)--(2,2)--(1.8,0);
\draw (2.3,2) node[fill=white] {$xy=0$};
\end{tikzpicture}%============================================

\item[10.] $|y|=1 \Leftrightarrow y=1 \;\text{or}\; y=-1$\\
\vspace{5mm}

%graph right side=============================================
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
\draw [->] (0,-4) --(0,-2)node[anchor=north east]{$-1$}-- (0,2)node[anchor=north east]{$1$}--(0,4)node[anchor=north east] {$y$};
\draw [->] (-4,0) --(0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$0$}-- (4,0)node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw (2,1) node {$|y|=1$};
\draw (-4,2)--(4,2) (-4,-2)--(4,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}%============================================

\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[11.]By the point-slop form of the equation of a line, an equation of the line throuth $(2,-3)$ with slope $6$ is\\
$y-(-3)=6(x-2)\quad \text{or} \quad y=6x-15.$   
\item[12.]$y-(-5)=-\frac{7}{2}[x-(-3)]\quad \text{or} \quad y=-\frac{7}{2}x-\frac{31}{2}$
\item[13.]The slope of the line throuth $(2,2)$ and $(1,6)$ is $m=\dfrac{6-1}{1-2}=-5$, so an equation of the line is \\
$y-1=-5(x-2)\quad \text{or} \quad y=-5x+11.$
\item[14.]For $(-1,-2)$ and $(4,3)$, $m=\dfrac{3-(-2)}{4-(-1)}=1$.An equation of the line is $y-3=1(x-4)\;\text{or}\; y=x-1.$ 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and you get

[image]

Comment: LuaLaTeX is also fine. If you add `\setsansfont{Arial Bold}` then you can use `\textsf{9.}` for enumeration say via `enumitem` package etc. Also the arrows are `stealth` but I'm almost sure that this is PSTricks output.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure about the following, but

- it looks to me, as if LaTeX was used to typeset the extract.
- I would also venture to say that the default LaTeX font Computer Modern or the newer Latin Modern were used.
- You could certainly create the graphics using `Tikz` or `PGFplots`.

You could probably force MS Word to look similar to this, but in my experience LaTeX does a much better job, especially if mathematics are involved.

Comment: Possibly the graphics was made with `pstricks` (the arrows of the axes lookk like the default arrw shape of pstricks. Easy to make it with pstricks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1: Preparing the diagrams

Compile the `diagram.tex` with

```
latex diagram.tex
dvips diagram.dvi
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None diagram.ps
```

to get `diagram.pdf` consisting of 2 pages.

```
% diagram.tex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3)[$x$,-90][$y$,180]
    \uput[-135](0,0){$0$}
    \rput[bl](1.5,1.5){\rnode[b]{b}{\rnode[bl]{bl}{$xy=0$}}}
    \psset{nodesep=1pt,arrows=->}
    \pcline(bl)(0,1)
    \pcline(b)(1,0)
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3)[$x$,-90][$y$,180]
    \psplot{-3}{3}{1.5}
    \psplot{-3}{3}{-1.5}
    \uput[-135](0,1.5){$1$}
    \uput[-135](0,0){$0$}
    \uput[-135](0,-1.5){$-1$}
    \rput(1.5,.75){$\lvert y\rvert=1$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

### Step 2: Importing the diagrams

Compile `main.tex` with

```
pdflatex main.tex
```

to obtain `main.pdf`.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=2cm

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{itemsep=12pt,label=\textbf{\arabic*.},start=9}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\begin{multicols}{2}
% 1
\item $xy=0\Leftrightarrow x=0 \text{ or } y=0$. The graph consists of the coordinate axes
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[page=1]{diagram}
\end{center}
% 2
\item $\lvert y\rvert =1 \Leftrightarrow y=1 \text{ or } y=-1$
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[page=2]{diagram}
\end{center}
\end{multicols}
% 3
\item By the point-slope form of the equation of a line, an equation of the line through $(2,-3)$ with slope $6$ is
$y-(-3)=6(x-2) \text{ or }  y=6x-15$.   
% 4
\item $y-(-5)=-\frac{7}{2}[x-(-3)] \text{ or }  y=-\frac{7}{2}x-\frac{31}{2}$
% 5
\item The slope of the line passing through $(2,2)$ and $(1,6)$ is $m=\dfrac{6-1}{1-2}=-5$, so an equation of the line is 
$y-1=-5(x-2)  \text{ or } y=-5x+11$.
% 6
\item For $(-1,-2)$ and $(4,3)$, $m=\dfrac{3-(-2)}{4-(-1)}=1$. An equation of the line is $y-3=1(x-4) \text{ or } y=x-1$. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should have changed your name to James Stewart this time around. :-) The text fonts and enumeration require some adjustment.